# How to revert to the future?

Tags: mercurial

I started a named branch several months ago which I then abandoned. Now I want to "restart" it. Specifically, I want to bring it up to the latest version of default and start working on it again.

I tried updating to the branch, and then reverting it to default,

```
hg revert -a -r default
```

But when I swap back and forth between this branch and the actual default I see 112 files have changed, so clearly they are not the same.

I ended up closing the branch, updating to default, force-switching back to my named branch again, and then force pushed (because it creates a new head).

Now my named branch is the same as default, but I have this short dead branch in my history now.

My questions are:

1. What was hg reverting to default doing? Was it reverting to the closest default ancestor rather than the tip of default? Even when I tried reverting to the tip via an explicit changeset, the two branches ended up different.
2. What is the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: The title of this question is priceless.

Answer (score 2):

> What was hg reverting to default doing?

For your (really bad )syntax:

> Using the -r/--rev or -d/--date options, revert the given files or directories to their states as of a specific revision

i.e to the state of latest ancestor in default branch for all files in repo

> I see 112 files have changed, so clearly they are not the same

Wrong assumption

> Because revert does not change the working directory parents, this will cause these files to appear modified.

I.e you **must commit** this *modified* Working Directory and diff (for testing) heads of branches *after it only*

> What is the "proper" way to do this?

Proper ways is

### If you want to save branch-specific changes and only update with latest changes

- Update to the head of abandoned branch
- Merge `default` branch to your branch
- Resolve all (if any) conflicts
- Commit mergeset

### If you want to have empty branch only and remove all changes from it

- Backout all changesets from branch
- Commit backout-changeset
- Merge default to branch